# How to map json values to jQuery UI's expected "value" and "label"?

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to get jQuery autocomplete working.  The problem is that my json array is composed of the properties "name" and "id".  jQuery expects "value" and "label".  I want to map "name" to "label" and "id" to "value".

Here is a working example, in which I'm using the expected jQuery property names:

```
    $(function() {
        var projects = [
            {value: "aaron-112", label: "Aaron"},
            {value: "andy-123", label: "Andy" },
            {value: "greg-122", label: "Greg" }];

        $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: projects,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                return false;
            }
        })
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });
    </script>

<div class="demo">
    <input id="project"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="project-id"/>
    </div>
```

But my json looks like this:

```
   [{id: "aaron-112", name: "Aaron"},
    {id: "andy-123", name: "Andy" },
    {id: "greg-122", name: "Greg" }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you modify the data before using it with the plugin?

For example:

```
var newProjects = [];
$.each(projects, function() { 
  newProjects.push( { value: this.id, label: this.name } );
});
```

And then use newProjects with the plugin?

Comment: Good Answer, That should do it!